# Snowflake connector query returning no results while the identical query returns results in the snowflake console

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using snowflake-connector-python 3.0.1 and Python 3.9.16.

The query I am attempting is this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM csd
LEFT JOIN mpm 
    ON mpm.gi_media_product = csd.media_product
JOIN mm mm 
    ON mm.csd_market = csd.market
JOIN gi ON (gi.dma_name = mm.gi_market) 
    AND (gi.media_name = csd.media_product OR gi.media_name = mpm.gi_media_product)
```

This query will work in the Snowflake console and return data but in the snowflake connector it returns no data.

The query will return items through the snowflake connector if the boolean is not wrapped in parentheses as seen here:

```
gi.mn = csd.mn OR gi.mn = mpm.mn
```

But the results from this query are not what I am looking for. So I am wondering if there is an issue with snowflake connector where it isn't parsing the parentheses correctly in a JOIN clause's conditionals.

I have tried alternative queries by explicitly and implicitly combining these two booleans/logic:

```
(gi.mn = csd.mn OR gi.mn = mpm.mn)
```

And all have worked in the console but not in the snowflake connector.

Here is one alternative query for example:

```
...
JOIN gi ON gi.dma = mm.dma
WHERE (gi.mn = csd.mn OR gi.mn = mpm.mn)
```

I am printing the query directly from the python application itself and using the same creds/warehouse/database to run the query in the snowflake console and getting results but there are no results when I run the query through the snowflake connector.

Am I missing something here or is this an issue with the snowflake connector?

EDIT:
Adding an less redacted query and some sample data so that it can be reproduced.

`csd.gi_media_product` is sometimes 'N/A' hence the OR operator.

Query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM csd
LEFT JOIN mpm
    ON mpm.csd_media_product = csd.media_product
JOIN  mm
    ON mm.csd_market = csd.market
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT dma_name, dma_id, media_name
    FROM gi 
) as gi
    ON gi.dma_name = mm.gi_market
    AND (gi.media_name = csd.gi_media_product OR gi.media_name = mpm.gi_media_product)
WHERE gi.media_name IS NOT NULL
```

csd:

```
ID,CONTRACT_ID,ADVERTISER,AE1USERID,AE2USERID,AE3USERID,PROGRAM,CAMPAIGN_ID,END_DATE,MARKET,MARKET_ID,MEDIA_PRODUCT,MEDIA_TYPE,QUANTITY,SALES_MARKET,START_DATE,STATUS,CAMPAIGN_SEGMENT_ID,GI_MEDIA_PRODUCT,DIGITAL_SCREENS
12345678-604707-Paid,12345678,some_business,some_user,,,some_program,123456,2023-07-02T04:00:00Z,NJ,7,2 Sheet,Rail,16,some_sales_market,2023-01-01T05:00:00Z,Paid,123456,N/A,
```

gi:

```
ID,GI_ID,SITE_ID,DIGITAL,CREATED_DTM,UPDATE_DTM,MEDIA_NAME,CLASSIFICATION_TYPE_NAME,MAX_FRAMES,MAX_HEIGHT,MAX_WIDTH,CONSTRUCTION_NAME,CONSTRUCTION_COUNT,CONSTRUCTION_TYPE_NAME,CONSTRUCTION_TYPE_DESCRIPTION,ILLUMINATION_TYPE_NAME,ILLUMINATION_TYPE_DESCRIPTION,MEDIA_TYPE_NAME,PLACEMENT_TYPE_NAME,ORIENTATION,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,DMA_ID,DMA_NAME,CBSA_CODE,CBSA_NAME,COUNTY_ID,COUNTY_NAME,ZIP_CODE,ZIP_CODE_NAME,STATE,TIME_ZONE,PERIOD,BASE_SEGMENT,TARGET_SEGMENT,TARGET_GEO,MARKET,INDEX_COMP_TARGET,PCT_COMP_POP_TARGET_INMKT,PCT_COMP_IMP_TARGET,PCT_COMP_IMP_TARGET_INMKT,FREQ_AVG,IMP_TARGET,IMP,REACH_NET,REACH_PCT,TRP,EFF_FREQ_MIN,EFF_FREQ_AVG,EFF_REACH_NET,EFF_REACH_PCT,PRODUCT_NAME,ACCOUNT_NAME,PARENT_ACCOUNT_NAME,PLACE_NAME,PLACE_SHORT_NAME,SPOT_IMPRESSIONS,SPOT_MEASURES_IMP_INMKT,IMP_INMKT,SPOT_MEASURES_IMP_TARGET_INMKT,IMP_TARGET_INMKT
50088217-2035-2023,12345678,some_site_id,FALSE,2020-01-27T15:09:47.828Z,2023-02-24T21:19:51.592Z,2-Sheet,Place Based,1,46,60,some_construction_name,1,Interior Wall,the wall inside of a building,Artificial Ambient,Surface illuminated by ambient artificial light source,Panel,Platform,0,50.843869,-79.078795,123,"some_dma_name",123456,"some_cbsa_name",12345,some_county_name,123456,"some_zip_code_name",NJ,-5,1,9330,2035,Defaulted to GLOBAL,Defaulted to GLOBAL,121,1,1,1,1.23,123,123,123,123,123,,,,,2023,some_account_name,some_parent_account_name,some_place_name,,123,123,123,123,123.79658731
```

mm:

```
CSD_MARKET,GI_MARKET
NYO,"New York, NY"
```

mpm:

```
CSD_MEDIA_PRODUCT,GI_MEDIA_PRODUCT
2 Sheet,2-Sheet
```

EDIT 2:
Here is the python script I am trying to run:

```
import os
import snowflake


def get_csd_data(self, cursor):
    connection = self.acquire_connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("USE SCHEMA g")

    query = """
        SELECT
            *
        FROM csd
        LEFT JOIN mpm
            ON mpm.csd_media_product = csd.media_product
        JOIN  mm
            ON mm.csd_market = csd.market
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT dma_name, dma_id, media_name
            FROM gi 
        ) as gi
            ON gi.dma_name = mm.gi_market
            AND (gi.media_name = csd.gi_media_product OR gi.media_name = mpm.gi_media_product)
        WHERE gi.media_name IS NOT NULL
    """
    cursor.execute(query)
    items = cursor.fetchall()
    
    return items

def acquire_connection(self):
    try:
        connection = snowflake.connector.connect(
            user=os.environ["snowflake_db_username"],
            password=os.environ["snowflake_db_password"],
            account=os.environ["snowflake_db_account"],
            database=os.environ["snowflake_db_name"],
            warehouse=os.environ["snowflake_db_warehouse"],
            autocommit=False
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise(e)
    else:
        return connection
```

Comment: We don't have enough data to reproduce here. Do the queries look identical in the logs?

Comment: are they both using same SQL? Can you pls print whole SQL that your py  is sending to SF?

Comment: Can you try adding this part in the Where clause   Where (gi.mn = csd.mn OR gi.mn = mpm.mn) and see if it returns data using the Snowflake connector. Also are the values in the column mn in table gi,csd or mpm Null.

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Added more data for you to reproduce. I don't have access to the snowflake logs, I'll have to ask the admin to give me access to that.

Comment: @KoushikRoy I've added the `print(query)` output to my question with less redacting. I've only changed the names of the databases. I am literally copying and pasting `print(query)` from the python into the snowflake console to check that it is working. I've validated that I am using the correct warehouse/db/schema/user.

Comment: @HimanshuKandpal If this is the query that you meant:
`JOIN gi ON gi.dma = mm.dma WHERE (gi.mn = csd.mn OR gi.mn = mpm.mn)`
Then it still does the same thing and returns 0 rows.

Comment: @jlam The query triggered via the Python connector is visible from Snowflake Query History. Can you compare it with the query you run from Snowflake console and see if they are they same?

Comment: @KoushikRoy
I've checked the query in the history and the query is identical. In the query history, the results indicate "No Results". So I exported the query directly to a worksheet and ran it and it returned results. I've copied and pasted the same query into the python script and it is not returning results, as in the `cursor.fetchall()` object has a length of 0.

Comment: @Sergiu see above comment

Comment: @jlam Maybe share a sample of your Python code?

Comment: @Sergiu added the script I am trying to run. I am running the `get_csd_data` function.

Comment: My guess: Are you using different roles to run the query? If they are identical one might have access to different set of data

Comment: @jlam Your code works for me (not sure why you pass cursor to get_csd_data function since you are obtaining it directly in the function, so I removed it on my case). So like Felipe mentioned are you sure you are using same user/role to run the same query via Snowflake UI? Your Python script doesn't sets a role, so I assume is the default one for the user. Can you make a test using same user/role from the Python script and the UI and confirm if you still see a difference?